# Durandal Composition Rendering

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

I am trying to replicate an SPA app from [John Papa's site](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/). I am stuck composing views using Durandal.

My code for the home view is below. I have only one root level as required by Durandal, so I am not sure why my two compose views are not displaying. If I remove the `<h2>`'s `data-bind`, then all is great in the world. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
<section> 
    <div id="intro">
        <h2 data-bind="html: displayName"></h2>
        <blockquote class="text-left">
            The electronic Cognitive Preference Estimator (e-CPE) provides insight into your preferred approach to problem solving and change management. 
            It takes just a few minutes to register and less than five minutes to complete the instrument.<br />
        </blockquote>
    </div>
<section  style="clear: both;" data-bind="compose: { view: 'bio' }"></section>
<footer data-bind="compose: { view: 'footer' }"></footer>
</section>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Compose two seperate views that have view models behind them?  Are the views showing when you remove the h2 tag, or what do you mean by all is great in the world?  Also, can you show your view models' code?  And if you already have a root and you are nested in the body, why are you putting a footer tag in there?

Comment: I failed to be clear in my first post. I am showing several sections on my home screen, such as a footer, bio section, and contact page. To keep the code on the home screen easier to read and manage, I broke up the code into separate views and now trying to rejoin them using the compose binding. The above code works, when there is not any additional binding. However, when I add any binding that is not a compose binding, my view composition does not display. The views that I am trying to compose do not have associated view models, but is there a difference in the binding if they did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are showing simple views from your HTML you should be able to use the composition module to do so.  If one of your sub-views has a binding error it will stop rendering the additional views and their bindings, but you should see that in your console.

FYI when I am simply showing a view that is bound to the current context I do so like this -

```
<!-- ko compose: 'shell/navbar.html' --><!-- /ko -->
```

Where shell is a folder inside my views folder and navbar.html contains my navbar.

Another thing to make sure is that your shell.js view model is exposing a displayName property that has semantically correct HTML if any.  Also double-check that bio and footer aren't throwing any binding errors.